# MongoDB 4.2 maxIdleTimeMS in a nodejs project

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have installed version 4.2.0 on MongoDB for windows as I need to use the maxIdleTimeMS option.

So my options look like this:

```
var options = {
    connectTimeoutMS: 50000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 360000,
    reconnectInterval: 1000,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    maxIdleTimeMS: 5000
}
```

But when I run it I get console:

```
WARN = the options [maxIdleTimeMS] is not supported
```

How can I fix this, as I know that version 4.2 supports it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maxIdleTimeMS is not supported by all the driver and the node driver does not support the maxIdleTimeMS.
you can achieve this by using `socketTimeoutMS`

Comment: So it would do the same thing?

Comment: yes, however be careful about setting it to lower than your longest running operation or you might inadvertently close sockets when you did not mean too.

Comment: What about if there's no way to know my longest operation? I thought it would just clear the idle connections. The problem is I end up having lots of opened connections that I no longer need so I need all idle and unused connections to clear

Comment: Everytime I need to query the db I'm calling a new connection like this: connect(onSuccess, onFailure) {
    try {
        var connection = mongoClient.connect(url, options);
        db = connection.db(database);
        onSuccess();
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log("Error,", err)
        onFailure(err)
    }
}

Comment: And this end's up with lots of opened connections

Comment: The socketTimeoutMS sets the number of milliseconds a socket stays inactive after the driver has successfully connected before closing. If the value is set to 30000 milliseconds, the socket closes if there is no activity during a 30 seconds window.

Comment: check if connection is alive or not before calling connect method  mongoDb.isConnected()